# How to convert number to time format in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert the number **20** into minutes with moment js. I need

```
21 to to look like 21:00
```

This way for my set interval the timer will show 19:58   to 0:01.

I had  tried

```
  var x = 1260000;
  var d = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');
  var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
  var mins = Math.floor(d.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
```

This still leaves me with 21.   I am not sure how to get the minutes form.

This seems like it shoud be a short fix.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can do this without moment.js using the standard constructor: *var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);*

Comment: Could you give us what input you've got, and what output you're trying to get? It's quite hard to pick apart your code without the context.

Comment: Sorry if that isn't clear.  I am trying get get the milliseconds to look like 21:00.  I need a countdown to go to 0:01.  However, i just keep getting 21

Answer (score 4):

```
var number = 15;
moment(number.toString(),"LT")
```

**output 15:00**

other method
    var value = 6.8 (exemple : 34/5 (34 hours of work / 5 days))
    /**
     * Convertion d'un nombre en Moment
     * @param value
     */
    convertNumberToMoment(value: number): moment.Moment {

```
    var hours = Math.floor(value);
    var minutes = Math.round((value % 1)*100)/100;

    return moment(hours + ':' + minutes * 60 + '0',"LT");       
}
```

**output 6:48**

Answer (score 1):

How to create a new moment object from hours-string and to display it as HH:MM :

`var input = '21';
 moment(input,'HH').format('HH:mm'); // 21:00`

Comment: Big thanks.  I have looking to convert this to a number though.   I tried parse int adn it gives me back 21.

Comment: Can you explain, exactly what you are trying to convert to number? Question was like  _"I need
`21 to to look like 21:00`"_

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: givnig invalid date

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plug-in and duration [`subtract`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/) method.

The plug-in lets you format duration object and with the `subtract` method you can modify duration value.

Here a working example that may help you:

```js
var $container = $('#timer');

var x = 1260000;
var d = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');

var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
  d.subtract(1, 's');
  if( d.seconds() >= 0 ){
    var timer = d.format('m:ss', { trim: false });
    $container.html(timer);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var moment = require("moment")
var x = 1260000;
var d = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');
moment(d.asMinutes(),'mm').format('mm:ss');
```